# How to implement a "include" jsp tag?

Tags: jsp, jsp-tags, jspinclude

I need to define a jsp tag which named "include". It should be used as:

```
<cms:include page="/aaa.jsp" />
```

It has an attribute `page` which points to another jsp, and it will include the content of that jsp and render it.

Is there any existing tag lib can do this? Or please give me some advises of implementing it, thanks!

---

**UPDATE**

From [Ramesh PVK's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9188714/342235) answer, I know there is a standard `<jsp:include>` fit my need.

But per my project's requirements, I can use the name `jsp:include`, but `cms:include`. I've already defined some other tags which have prefix `cms`, and the `include` one should have the same prefix.

Is it possible to find the `tld` file for `jsp:include`? That I can copy the declarations to my tld file to reuse the tag with new prefix.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Already there is a standard jsp tag for this.

```
This is to include page at runtime.
<jsp:include page="includedPage" />
```

and

```
This is to include page at compile time.
<%@ include file="banner.jsp" %>
```

**Links:**

- [See this tutorial](http://java.sun.com/j2ee/tutorial/1_3-fcs/doc/JSPIntro8.html)
- [Reference](http://java.sun.com/products/jsp/tags/12/syntaxref1214.html)
- [Different between jsp:include and @include](http://www.daniweb.com/web-development/jsp/threads/105695)

Comment: in that case, include tag has to be defined in your tag library. Implment a tag which does pageContext.include("").

Answer (score 0):

There is already an include tag in JSP that include other static or dynamic JSP or other resource in current JSP. Your requirement is exact same and can be done by jsp include tag. You can learn more on JSP Include tag and other JSP related things on [apekshit.com](http://www.apekshit.com/t/71/JSP-Include-Tag)

Comment: The main point is that I can't use `jsp:` prefix for this tag.