# Bring common code into a separate jsp

Tags: java, html, jsp, spring-mvc

I have more than two jsp pages. And into every page I have a common jsp code like this(navigation bar)

```
<nav>
    <div class="nav-wrapper green darken-1 ">
        <a href="#" class="brand-logo left"> SBT</a>
        <ul id="nav-mobile" class="right hide-on-med-and-down">
            <li><a href="menu">Menu</a></li>
            <li><a href="home">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="test">Test</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

I don't wanna copy this or even more then this part into every jsp page. How to connect nav.jsp, which contain this code to every jsp page. And will it work slower or faster?

Comment: you can use [jsp include](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9188478/how-to-implement-a-include-jsp-tag) tag

Comment: possible duplicate of [Include another JSP file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9110148/include-another-jsp-file)

Comment: where should I use it. And will it download nav bar before other elements on my page? I need to see it first

Comment: check the link in my comment

Comment: <jsp:include page="nav.jsp"></jsp:include>

Comment: Thanks guys! I'm going to do this

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7879906/what-is-the-difference-between-jspinclude-page-and-include-file

Answer (score 1):

Create 3rd file say nav.jsp write your common code into it and simply include your nav.jsp wherever you want 
     You can use include action or include directive(consider the Advantage of both the ways and use the way which is convenient to you).